# How to make HTTP requests in angular and get the body from the object?

Tags: angular, observable

[This is the Image of the API request results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olu1D.png)

Here I am writing a service named `FaqService` to make `HTTP` request and calling that service in a component .

```
getServers(data: string){
    return this.http.get(Staticdata.apiBaseUrl + "/2.2/search/advanced?key="+ Staticdata.key +"&access_token="+ Staticdata.access_token +"&/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&closed=True&title=" + data + Staticdata.redirectUrl + "&filter="+ Staticdata.filters)
        .map(
        (response: Response) => {
            const items = response.json();
            return items;
        })
    .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
   }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
  onRecievingResults(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.router.navigate(['results'], {relativeTo: this.route});

    this.faqService.getServers(value)
        .subscribe(
        (item: any[]) => {
            console.log(item);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    ); 
}
```

Here in this HTML template how do i pass through the API results and get the    body.

```
</div>
<div  class="entryTitle" *ngFor = "let item of items">
<h1>Search results for :{{ item.body }}</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: What issue you exactly are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ item.body }}` will refer to `this.item.body` in your component. So you'll need to create a field:

```
public item; // <------- add the field
onRecievingResults(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.router.navigate(['results'], {relativeTo: this.route});

    this.faqService.getServers(value)
        .subscribe(
        (item: any[]) => {
            console.log(item);
            this.item = item; // <------- assign it here
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    ); 
}
```

and change your html to:

```
<h1>Search results for :{{ item?.body }}</h1>
```

for a truthy check.

Comment: @KaranDesai oh I didn't see that. I thought it was a scope issue since OP wasn't assigning the response to `this.items`. If that's not the case, you are right.

Comment: @KaranDesai yes i wanted it to be printed

Comment: Yes I realized it later. Comment deleted :)